# AngularJS namespace for function call in view template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

I have a div with controller like this

```
<div ng-controller= "merchandiseListCtrl as ml">
```

In the js file, I have a couple of function calls and render an object on return.

```
  vm.getlaptopTotal = (productCatergory) => getTotal(productCatergory);

  var getTotal = function (_) {
    var res = {
      count: 0,
      total: 0,
      products: []
    };
    _.map((item) =>{
      if(item.purchased){
        res.count += 1;
        res.total += item.price;
        res.products.push(item.product);
      }
    });
    return res;
  };
```

So, it is obvious that I'm returning obj res with properties: count, total, and products.

In the HTML view template, I want to have to shorter namespace, shortcut to reduce the pattern `ml.fn(x).products` of my function call to return the properties' values for some fields. In other words, I want to assign something like `ng-bind ='myTotal = ml.fn(x)'`, but then I run into ton of errors about `$rootScope`. What should I do to have a better namespace for this scenario, and complexity may go this far: `funcObj.subobj.property.childproperty.grandchildproperty` ? So accessibility and readibility can be accomplished?

Here is my HTML code

```
        <div>{{ml.myTotal = ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)}}>
          <!-- display the selection -->
          Laptop count: {{ ml.myTotal.count }} units
          <br>
          <div ng-if="ml.myTotal.products">
            <ul ng-repeat="product in ml.myTotal.products">
              <li>{{$index+1}}) {{product}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <br>
        </div>
```

EDIT 1: Ran into [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops).products%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.myTotal%20%3D%20ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops).products%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.myTotal%20%3D%20ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops).products%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.myTotal%20%3D%20ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops).products%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.myTotal%20%3D%20ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops).products%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%5D%7D,%7B%22msg%22:%22ml.myTotal%20%3D%20ml.getlaptopTotal(ml.laptops)%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22count%22:0,%22total%22:0,%22products%22:%5B%5D%7D%7D%5D%5D) because now the products array,  funcObj().products is dynamic. Don't know how to fix yet. But previously, I use funcObj() as an ng-click event handler.

Thanks,